# SQL - Select Top averages

Tags: mysql

How can I retrieve average of each distinct entity (venue_id  in this case) and also top n averages (AVG) from database

I have the following table

```
stars   | venue_id
--------|---------
3       |5
2       |5
1       |2
2       |7
2       |7
4       |1
```

How to retrive following results:

I want average stars from each distinct venue_id as "avg_rating". 

**Average Ratings**

```
venue_id    | avg_rating
------------|------------
5           |2.5
2           |1
7           |2
1           |4
```

Also, I am running in problem to select the following result. I want top N of average stars or average rating. 

**Top 2 Ratings**

```
venue_id    | avg_rating
------------|-------
1           |4
5           |2.5
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have tried SELECT AVG(stars) FROM table_name but I could get only one row which averages entire stars of the table_name. Also I could not google to select TOP N average results using MySQL. This is big problem for me. Hope you can help.

Comment: Theres your problem right there. If you are wanting the venue_id as well, you need to include it in your query. You are saying you need it, yet when you dont include it you dont get the results you want. That is because without it you get the total average not the average per venue. If you include the venue_id you will get the average per venue.

Comment: No Josh Mein you're wrong. I have tried `SELECT venue_id, AVG(stars) AS avg_rating FROM venue_ratings` but I get only one row with average of entire tables stars. The answer by davek worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    venue_id
    , avg(stars) as avg_rating
from myTable 
group by venue_id
order by avg(stars) desc
-----------------------
-- and to get the top 2
-----------------------
limit 2
```